# Grabbing process stderr in scala

Tags: scala, process, stderr

When using the scala 2.9 process API, I can do things like

```
"ls -l"!
```

which will send the process stdout and stderr into my own.
Or:

```
val output = "ls -1"!!
```

which will return whatever was sent to stdout into the val output.

How can I similarly grab stderr?

Comment: Honestly -- dunno. StdErr is 2. That's all I can contribute :\

Comment: I can always do bash trickery, but I want to do it the scala way.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can create your own ProcessLogger:

```
import sys.process._

val logger = ProcessLogger(
    (o: String) => println("out " + o),
    (e: String) => println("err " + e))

scala> "ls" ! logger
out bin
out doc
out lib
out meta
out misc
out src
res15: Int = 0

scala> "ls -e" ! logger
err ls: invalid option -- e
err Try `ls --help' for more information.
res16: Int = 2
```

Edit: The previous example simply prints, but it could easily store the output in some structure:

```
val out = new StringBuilder
val err = new StringBuilder

val logger = ProcessLogger(
    (o: String) => out.append(o),
    (e: String) => err.append(e))

scala> "ls" ! logger
res22: Int = 0

scala> out
res23: StringBuilder = bindoclibmetamiscsrc

scala> "ls -e" ! logger
res27: Int = 2

scala> out
res28: StringBuilder =

scala> err
res29: StringBuilder = ls: invalid option -- eTry `ls --help' for more information.
```

Comment: I need to also log the actual command, how to do that? For example "ls"!! would print two lines "cmd: ls" and "out: somefile".

Comment: @sscarduzio I think the quickest way is to just grab the name of the command before you execute it..

Comment: The quickest way to code this is to instantiate ProcessLogger inline and let it know the command as a closure (after grabbing the command into a variable as mentioned by @sscarduzio). e.g. `"ls -e" ! ProcessLogger((e: String) => println(commandName + " error: " + e)`

Comment: @matanster that example will print stdout too.Try something that generates both stdout and stderr and it will print both e.g. `"ls . *.blah"` or if there's no error and only stdout it will print that.

Comment: Why below code didn't work?

import sys.process._
val stdout = new StringBuilder
val stderr = new StringBuilder

val status = "ls -al FRED" ! ProcessLogger(line => stdout.append(line), line => stderr.append(line))

{ on Scala 2.12.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_152) }