# How to stream stdout in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Basically, I have a program whose output goes to stdout. I am running that program from within my Scala code. What I do right now is to redirect the output to a file. Something like this.

```
val cmd = progName + " " + arguments 
cmd #> new java.io.File(outputFilePath) !
```

I also have to later process that output file. That is why this approach is slow, as I have to first wait for the program to have finished and everything written to the output file. What I would prefer is to have content of the stdout being streamed so that from another thread I could read the contents as they are being streamed. In this way, I can process the data while the program I am running from Scala is running.

Moreover, the data in the output file is delimited by newlines. Is there a way, I could get the data line by line as the program is running.

Lastly, is there something in Java to do that, which I can also then use in Scala?

Comment: Have a look at Scala [ProcessBuilder](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder) to see how to redirect stdout

Comment: I don't know enough about Scala to be sure, but this might be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5564667/1863564).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ProcessBuilder has a [`lineStream`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder@lineStream:Stream[String]) method, which I think does exactly what you want. It returns a `Stream[String]` that lets you process the output as it becomes available.

Here's a simple program with slow output for testing, which I saved as `slow-printer.scala`:

```
// slow-printer.scala
for (i <- 1 to 10) {
  println(i)
  Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

You can stream the output (1 line per second) from the program like this:

```
import scala.sys.process._

val lines = "scala slow-printer.scala".lineStream

lines foreach println
```

---

If you're stuck with 2.10, or maybe if your output isn't newline-delimited, then you can use `ProcessIO` to handle the output instead:

```
import scala.sys.process._

Seq("scala", "slow-printer.scala").run(new ProcessIO(
  _.close(), // stdin
  out => { // stdout
    val src = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(out)
    for (line <- src.getLines()) {
      println(line)
    }
  },
  _.close() // stderr
))
```

Comment: Do "val lines = ...." and "lines foreach println" run in parallel here?

Comment: Yes, the sub-process runs in parallel with the lines being printed in the main Scala program. Try it! You'll see one line printed per second.

Comment: Which version of Scala does this require? Because I'm getting the following error, <console>:38: error: value lineStream is not a member of String
       val lines = "./my-cmd.sh".lineStream
                                 ^
<console>:34: error: value foreach is not a member of Int
              lines foreach println

Comment: The documentation link I provided is for the current stable version, which is 2.11.8. I'm running 2.11.7.

Comment: I see. I was testing on version 2.10. Let me try with 2.11.7.

Comment: The `lineStream` method was added in 2.11.0, which was released back in April 2014. I would recommend using the current stable version (2.11.8), not my slightly outdated version.

Comment: I am using Apache Spark, and the prebuilt packages use Scala 2.10. For 2.11, I will have to build a binary of Spark myself. That is the bad part. Any idea how a similar thing can be achieved using Spark 2.10?

Comment: I've found one solution for 2.10. The answer by eivindw at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563439/grabbing-process-stderr-in-scala. I think its doing a similar thing as your code. Although, I think I would have to manage looking at new lines myself.

Comment: Ah, I see. There are other ways to handle this, which should be 2.10 compatible. I've updated the answer.